# I want to get an array of users whose last name begins with 'x' using the Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql-9.4

I have tried such things as:

```
users=User.where :conditions => "last_name LIKE ?" "%X"
and
users=User.where("last_name.each_char.first = 'X'")
and
users=User.where(:last_name.to_s.char.first => "X")
and
users=User.where "last_name.initial" == "X"
users=User.where("last_name".start_with ? "X")
users=User.where("last_name".match(/^X/))
users=User.where(:last_name[0] == "X")
```

and a whole bunch more failed attempts. 
user.last_name is a valid string, and I think I understand why :last_name, which is a symbol, didn't work, so I also did "last_name"[0] and :last_name.to_a[0]

Some of the attempts, such as this one

```
[64] pry(main)> user=User.where("last_name[0] = 'X'").all
 User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE (last_name[0]     = 'X')
=> #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x3723938>
```

returned an active record relation
Any help most appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close! Try: `User.where('last_name like ?', 'x%')`.

Comment: For more context, the where clause is being run on the database, not in ruby/rails, so you have to use the appropriate, probably sql, syntax.

Comment: Boy I danced all around that one! Thanks much Daryn.